# Volley Request not working in this class, am I using it incorrectly?

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

Below is my class for handling http requests. I have tried the Volley Request in a new Android Project with no other code and the request is handled properly and I receive the result I expected. But for some reason when I use this code in my working project as a class, it doesn't return any response.

The way I call the request is:

```
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    String url = "some-url";
    String urlReturn = request.getFromURL(url, <ACTIVITY>.this);
```

where `<ACTIVITY>` is the activity I am calling the request from and `"some-url"` is a url that returns a string of data.

```
public class HttpRequest {

String response_test = "";

        public String getFromURL (String url, Context context) {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.e("response1", response);
                            response_test = "1";
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("log2=", error.toString());
                            //requestQueue.stop();
                        }
                    });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            requestQueue.start();

            return response_test;

        }
```

`response_test` never changes, so `onResponse` is never called. I thought there may be a timing issue, but when I add loop for it to wait until `response_test` is changed, it waits forever. Any idea what may be the issue? Anything I may have overlooked in how I'm calling this class?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the request after you start the queue. Also, response_test will not return what you expect since the call is Async.

Comment: Is on errorResponse called?

Comment: And something else- Volley is async library- you are returning, before the library itself do its work. See your logcat if the messages are there

Comment: If you get a volley error the response_test string will not change. Have you debugged it?

Comment: I have tried debugging on onResponse and errorReponse, both are not called. @X3Btel,

Comment: I copy pasted your code and its working- try to cleast cache and restart android studio or if your endpoint is working

Comment: @X3Btel yes I also tried copying and pasting into a brand new android project without any other logic. A simple request from the same URL works fine. I don't see why it wouldn't work as part of a class though.

Comment: I did copied the class as well but. Can you try something else-  Move the queue init out of the method call. In the activity or in the class constructor

Answer (score 0):

Volley is async library. It does work on another thread and when the call is ready it executes the code in onResponse. In the example you are returning imideately. Check your logcat for the messages they should be there

Comment: I realize this, which is why I make the main thread wait to see if the messages are showing up later. No logcat output from the Volley thread shows up.